# Map Network drives over VPN Ignoring DFS

Tags: vpn, network-shares

We have 15 sites running DFS so GPO maps to the DFS Shares, Issue is the AD looks at the IP and maps the DFS to the local Site, VPN uses its own IP range, thus not allowing users access to their site DFS Share.
I need a script that will look at AD, Map the Shares to the sites shares, I want a script that I can put on the Laptops that have VPN.
Each site has its own AD Group, so if the script can check this and then map the 6 drives to that sites server that would be great. this would need to be a bat of vbs script. Can someone please help?

user 1 in office 1 (AD Group Site 1) connecting to share on Server in office 1 (site IP) 192.168.1.x

user 2 in office 2 (AD Group Site 2) connecting to share on Server in office 2 (site IP) 192.168.2.x

user 3 in office 3 (AD Group Site 3) connecting to share on Server in office 3 (site IP) 192.168.3.x

At present I have a BAT file on each laptop with net use S: \server xyz\shared$ but I would like a bat / vbs that would check AD membership and map to their office server
User 1 comes in on VPN, 10.1.0.x needs to get to Server in Location 1
User 3 comes in on VPN, 10.1.0.x needs to get to server in Location 3

DFS locations for each = \company\shared = \Server\shared$ looking at IP of client.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution in my opinion is using **Group Policy Item-level targeting** to specify mapped drivers based on group membership:

1. Edit GPO > User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Drive Maps > open Mapped Drive properties
2. Navigate to Common tab, enable Item-level targeting, and add a "User in group" rule to limit that mapping to a specific AD group
3. Create a targeted mapping like this for each site and for each drive

---

Depending on your network, there are some other directions to consider:

- If your Site-specific content is split into separate folders like `\\domain.tld\share\Office1\`, then you can use DFS Folders to say that content only lives on the Office1 server, and clients will connect appropriately.
- You can use DFS Replication to make Office1/2/3 content available in the default site (or in all sites). Then users who get referred to the default site can still access those files.
- You may be able to configure the VPN to be site-aware, placing users in a specific subnet (assigned to Site1/2/3) based on AD groups.